# Event to get Customer or Visiter Id

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, event-observer, customer

I am trying to get when the Id of Customer or Visitor on every page load from customer/visitor session through event.

I had used this `controller_front_init_before` event for the purpose but don't know if it is the proper one because sometimes (don't know the reason for sure, maybe it's fired too early) it returned empty session for both.

So my question is when the customer/visitor session gets initialized ? 
and which event should be used to get the session ?
and is it the proper one `controller_front_send_response_before` to use or there is a better choice I don't know of ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found an event that could correspond to what you are looking for : **customer_session_init**

```
   app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php, line 75.
    Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_session_init', array('customer_session'=>$this));
```

It may not be updated to the last version of Magento, but I found this information on this event list : https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-8/

Comment: called very early & also more then 10 times, also doesn't returned the visitor data if the visitor is not customer